# How efficiently fetch items from Core Data using NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In Core Data I have an Entity with a date field and I want to display all items on UI for a specific date range. For example, I want to show a list of items for the current month with the ability to switch the month.

I found that the best way to do this would be using `NSFetchedResultsController` with using `sectionNameKeyPath` which would be computed based on the `date` field like this:

```
extension MyEntity {
   var sectionId: String {
      // convert date to year+month_number
   }
}
```

With this solution, I would get separate sections of items for each month and also not have empty pages where there are no items for that date range.

The problem is when there are many items in the storage - it takes too much time to fetch them cause NSFetchedResultsController fetches all of them at once by default. I tried to use `fetchLimit`, but that does not work for me, because it limits the number of fetched objects, but in my case, I would need to limit the number of fetched sections.

I was also thinking about just having a predicate that would limit the date range like this

```
date > startOfMonth & date < endOfMonth
```

But then I don't know if there are any items for that date range and I don't want to show an empty list.

Is there any way I can fetch a limited number of sections? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Use fetchLimit together with sorting?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm not sure how would I know what limit to set? I would need to know how items are in a section before I actually do fetch the sections.